# Adding Microsoft Windows FIDO2 login support for my device

Tags: windows, windows-10, fingerprint, fido-u2f, fido

It has been announced that Windows 10 will support FIDO2 logging (https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-hello-adding-support-fido2-security-keys). Аs far as I understand the support there is support for devices from some producers like YubiKey to work with FIDO2 on Windows login.

My company has produced a device that allows passwordless authentication: it is a smartcard with a fingerprint reading functionality. Does anybody know how should we approach the topic of adding support for our device with the Windows 10 FIDO2 logging?

We would like to achieve such effect so that once the drivers of our device are installed on a client machine, we could like the device to allow the user (once their fingerprint is registered) to log into Windows in passwordless manner with FIDO2 i.e. by having the user to connect the smartcard via USB and scan their finger on the device.

Can anybody suggest me directions I could follow on delivering support for it with Windows 10 FIDO2?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted on my answer. If you are unsure of anything or have any questions, let me know, and I will try to help and improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for starters, click on this link : https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2018/04/17/password-less-sign-in-to-windows-10-azure-ad-using-fido2-is-coming-soon-plus-other-cool-news/

Now, For a deep dive into the subject and to find an in-built practical link at last, click on this link : 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2018/04/17/windows-hello-fido2-security-keys/

Finally, for the related API links and coding stuff, click here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/windows-integration/web-authentication